# memory leak issue occurred due to creation of data url (image) in fabric js canvas

Tags: canvas, memory, memory-leaks, fabricjs, todataurl

Memory issue occurred, when adding an image to the canvas using data url.
Data url is created from image which were downloaded from axios.
Images are not getting cleared in the memory unless we close the browser.

[image]

```
axios.get(/getImage, {
            params: {
                'path': imgPath
            },
            responseType: 'arraybuffer'
        })
        .then(response => {
          let stringData = Buffer.from(response.data, 'binary').toString('base64');
          let data_url = "data:application/octet-stream;base64," + stringData;

            fabric.Image.fromURL(
                data_url,img => {
                               data_url="";
                               resolve(img);
                               });
             });
});
```